# Creating an Attachments Custom Field for a Custom Object?

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, attachment

We have a custom object in Salesforce and I would like to know if there is a way to add an attachments field to the page layout so that users can upload screenshots if they needed to.I know we can add Notes and Attachments as related list.Any other way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not something I would want to do, but if you needed it to be a field on the object, you could just add a rich text field to the object.  Users could add all the screenshot images to that field.  That way the images would be visible on the standard view page.

Again, I would agree with @sfdcfox, that it is best to use the standard functionality, but this is a workaround that could offer this capability.

Answer (score 1):

The only other means would be to create a Visualforce page to upload the attachments in; they couldn't just click "edit" and have an upload field without a Visualforce page taking over the edit screen. You're probably better off letting them use the standard functionality.